When is $\Vert A+B \Vert = \Vert X + X^\dagger \Vert$ for $[A, X; X^\dagger, B] \succcurlyeq 0$?
Given
$$
H = \begin{pmatrix} A & X \\ 
X^\dagger & B
 \end{pmatrix} 
\succcurlyeq 0  , 
$$
with $A \succcurlyeq 0$ meaning $A$ is positive semi-definite (and Hermitian)
and $A, B, X$ are $n\times n$ (complex) matrices,
when is $\Vert A+B \Vert = \Vert X + X^\dagger \Vert$ for the nuclear norm $\Vert A \Vert = \text{Tr}(\sqrt{A A^\dagger})$?
Ref [1] below proves that in this case $\Vert X + X^\dagger \Vert \leq \Vert A + B \Vert$ for any unitarily-invariant norm (e.g., the nuclear norm above). So I'm looking for conditions when this inequality is saturated.
Any help is appreaciated.
[1] https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/reports/hiroshimamingwolk13.pdf
